# Camel OSGI - Camel Spring Boot calling external routes

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

When running in an OSGI environment i am able to call camel routes contained is separate projects via use of direct-vm, is it possible to something similar when running camel projects as individual spring boot apps or would i need to stand up REST endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, each Spring Boot application is a separate JVM process. You need to use a protocol over http/tcp or something for communication, even on same host.